# I can't login with Mariadb root

Tags: mysql

I'm connected to my cloud. I can login with Mariadb root with this command:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Then I created a new user bill with host %

```
CREATE USER 'bill'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'passpass';
```

Granted all the privileges to user bill:

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'bill'@'%' with grant option;
```

when i entered it I got this error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

Please give me answer as soon as possible.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about `sudo mysql -u root` ?

Comment: Remove `with grant option` and then try again.

Comment: I have root priviledge

Comment: grant all privileges on *.* to 'bill'@'%'; I have try it but again same error is coming

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui Please don't suggest ever again, to simply try with `sudo` when something doesn't work, when you have no clue what the problem is.

Comment: @jwala Access is denied for root user. Any chance you tried this with the password of bill?

Comment: well no, there is not any miss match about password.